# Как добавить строку в текстовый файл?

Tags: golang

Как добавить/добавлять строки в конец файла?
У меня есть функция, но она затирает, удаляет содержимое файла.

```
func createFile(){
file, err := os.Create("demo.txt")
if err != nil {
    return
}
defer file.Close()

file.WriteString("My name is Mike")
```

Answer (score 2):

Решение:

```
package main

import "os"

func main(){
    f, err := os.OpenFile("test.txt", os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    if _, err = f.WriteString("My name is Mike"); err != nil {
    panic(err)
    }
}
```